# Selenium unable to click 2nd, 3rd & 4th radio buttons

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I have a script to click the mandatory radio buttons. It works well with the first button but not with others. I have tried various `xpath` but still not sure why `webdriver` is unable to click the 2nd, 3rd and 4th radio buttons.
My code:

```
def N_days(self, days):
    #action = ActionChains(self.driver)
    if days==5:
        print("selected 5 days")
        self.driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH,value="(//label[@class='mat-radio-label'])[1]").click()
    elif days==10:
        print("selected 10 days")
        self.driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value="(//label[@class='mat-radio-label'])[2]").click()
    elif days==20:
        print("selected 20 days")
        self.driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value="(//label[@class='mat-radio-label'])[3]").click()
    elif days==30:
        print("selected 30 days")
        self.driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value="(//label[@class='mat-radio-label'])[4]").click()
```

The other paths I tried for condition `days==10` are:

```
value="//span[@class='mat-radio-label-content' and contains(.,'10')]"
value="(//span[@class='mat-radio-label-content'])[2]"
```

This is the screen when the script is executing:
[image: runtime window]

The HTML part of the section is:

```html
<mat-form-field class="cds-mb-5 mat-form-field ng-tns-c9-3 mat-primary mat-form-field-type-mat-input mat-form-field-appearance-legacy mat-form-field-can-float mat-form-field-should-float mat-form-field-hide-placeholder ng-star-inserted ng-dirty ng-touched" xpath="1"><div class="mat-form-field-wrapper">
  <div class="mat-form-field-flex">

    <div class="mat-form-field-infix">
      
  <mat-radio-group class="mat-radio-group ng-dirty ng-valid ng-touched" fxlayout="column" role="radiogroup" style="flex-direction: column; box-sizing: border-box; display: flex;">
    <!----><!---->
      <mat-radio-button class="mat-radio-button mat-primary ng-star-inserted" color="primary" tabindex="-1" id="mat-radio-2">

<label class="mat-radio-label" for="mat-radio-2-input" style="">
  
  <span class="mat-radio-container">
    <span class="mat-radio-outer-circle"></span>
    <span class="mat-radio-inner-circle"></span>
    <input class="mat-radio-input cdk-visually-hidden" type="radio" id="mat-radio-2-input" tabindex="0" name="mat-radio-group-0" value="5" aria-label="N Products" aria-labelledby="N Products" aria-describedby="">

    
    <span class="mat-radio-ripple mat-focus-indicator mat-ripple" mat-ripple="">

      <span class="mat-ripple-element mat-radio-persistent-ripple"></span>
    </span>
  </span>

  
  <span class="mat-radio-label-content">
    
    <span style="display:none">&nbsp;</span>
    5
      
  </span>
</label>
</mat-radio-button>
    <!---->
      <mat-radio-button class="mat-radio-button mat-primary ng-star-inserted mat-radio-checked" color="primary" tabindex="-1" id="mat-radio-3">

<label class="mat-radio-label" for="mat-radio-3-input" style="">
  
  <span class="mat-radio-container">
    <span class="mat-radio-outer-circle"></span>
    <span class="mat-radio-inner-circle"></span>
    <input class="mat-radio-input cdk-visually-hidden" type="radio" id="mat-radio-3-input" tabindex="0" name="mat-radio-group-0" value="10" aria-label="N Products" aria-labelledby="N Products" aria-describedby="">

    
    <span class="mat-radio-ripple mat-focus-indicator mat-ripple" mat-ripple="">

      <span class="mat-ripple-element mat-radio-persistent-ripple"></span>
    </span>
  </span>

  
  <span class="mat-radio-label-content" style="background: rgb(204, 136, 136); border: 2px solid red;">
    
    <span style="display:none">&nbsp;</span>
    10
      
  </span>
</label>
</mat-radio-button>
    <!---->
      <mat-radio-button class="mat-radio-button mat-primary ng-star-inserted" color="primary" tabindex="-1" id="mat-radio-4">

<label class="mat-radio-label" for="mat-radio-4-input" style="">
  
  <span class="mat-radio-container">
    <span class="mat-radio-outer-circle"></span>
    <span class="mat-radio-inner-circle"></span>
    <input class="mat-radio-input cdk-visually-hidden" type="radio" id="mat-radio-4-input" tabindex="0" name="mat-radio-group-0" value="20" aria-label="N Products" aria-labelledby="N Products" aria-describedby="">

    
    <span class="mat-radio-ripple mat-focus-indicator mat-ripple" mat-ripple="">

      <span class="mat-ripple-element mat-radio-persistent-ripple"></span>
    </span>
  </span>

  
  <span class="mat-radio-label-content">
    
    <span style="display:none">&nbsp;</span>
    20
      
  </span>
</label>
</mat-radio-button>
    <!---->
      <mat-radio-button class="mat-radio-button mat-primary ng-star-inserted" color="primary" tabindex="-1" id="mat-radio-5">

<label class="mat-radio-label" for="mat-radio-5-input" style="">
  
  <span class="mat-radio-container">
    <span class="mat-radio-outer-circle"></span>
    <span class="mat-radio-inner-circle"></span>
    <input class="mat-radio-input cdk-visually-hidden" type="radio" id="mat-radio-5-input" tabindex="0" name="mat-radio-group-0" value="30" aria-label="N Products" aria-labelledby="N Products" aria-describedby="">

    
    <span class="mat-radio-ripple mat-focus-indicator mat-ripple" mat-ripple="">

      <span class="mat-ripple-element mat-radio-persistent-ripple"></span>
    </span>
  </span>

  
  <span class="mat-radio-label-content">
    
    <span style="display:none">&nbsp;</span>
    30
      
  </span>
</label>
</mat-radio-button>
    
  </mat-radio-group>
  <input class="mat-input-element mat-form-field-autofill-control cdk-text-field-autofill-monitored" hidden="" matinput="" id="mat-input-1" aria-invalid="false" aria-required="false">
  
      <span class="mat-form-field-label-wrapper">
        <!---->
      </span>
    </div>

    <!---->
  </div>

  
  <!----><div class="mat-form-field-underline ng-tns-c9-3 ng-star-inserted">
    <span class="mat-form-field-ripple"></span>
  </div>

  <div class="mat-form-field-subscript-wrapper">
    <!---->
    <!----><div class="mat-form-field-hint-wrapper ng-tns-c9-3 ng-trigger ng-trigger-transitionMessages ng-star-inserted" style="opacity: 1; transform: translateY(0%);">
      
      <!---->
      <div class="mat-form-field-hint-spacer"></div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</mat-form-field>
```

The HTML page won't be accessible since it's an internal tool.
Any help would be great.
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: is it throwing any error?

Comment: No error. It just skips the click action and proceeds to next steps

Comment: Try `//input[@type='radio' and @value='5']`, `//input[@type='radio' and @value='10']`, `//input[@type='radio' and @value='20']`...

Comment: @JaSON There's no input tag in the html.

Comment: Hmmm... I don't think so:)

Comment: @LibinThomas : is url publicly accessible?

Comment: @KunduK it's not. I have attached the HTML snippet if you want to take a look

Comment: @JaSON I tried your snippet too, it didn't work as the values are inside multiple ```span``` tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all radio buttons are inside mat-radio-button (descendant elements) we can try with

```
//mat-radio-button/descendant::input[@value="10"]
```

Comment: I added a sleep of 5 secs and used your suggestion, and it worked well! Thanks :)